# contradictory chrome browser error messages "out of date"

Tags: google-chrome

about://help says it is fine, but the upper right corner menu says it is out of date. I have tried the google search and also tried to find similar issues in superuser with no apparent solution. this is on mac el Capitan.

[screenshot of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38arB.png)

Comment: I noticed this the other day and that message did not go away until I closed ALL instances of Chrome from the machine and then restarted it. Let me know if that may be the issue you're experiencing? If all fails, reboot the laptop and check again in case it's as simple a fix as that -- assuming closing all instances and opening a new one doesn't resolve like it did for me.

Comment: Restart your Mac and see it it changes or no.On my Windows, my latest version of Chrome is 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit)

Comment: Thank you both so much. Yes, the error went away after I restarted chrome (restarting mac would have done the same thing. If you move your comments to answers I will use both as solutions.